# Clarification of a theorem mentioned in a paper on RED

Tags: entanglement, entanglement-swapping

I am reading a paper "*A study of Teleportation and Super Dense Coding capacity in Remote Entangled Distribution*" ([arXiv:1210.1312](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1312)). In this paper Relations on two-qubit pure states are mentioned.

Consider a resource entangled in 2 $\otimes $ 2 dimensions. These states are given by

$| {\psi_{12}} \rangle $ = $\sum_{i, j}a_{ij} |ij \rangle $ and

$| {\psi_{23}} \rangle $ = $\sum_{p, q}b_{pq} |pq \rangle $

where $\sum_{i, j}a_{ij}^2 = 1 $, $\sum_{p, q}b_{pq}^2 = 1 $

Alice and Bob share a pure entangled state $| {\psi_{12}} \rangle $ between them, Bob and Charlie also share another entangled state $| {\psi_{23}} \rangle $.

In order to swap the entanglement, Bob carries out measurement on his qubits. Bob carries out measurement for his two qubits in a non-maximally Bell-type entangled basis given by the basis vectors

$| \phi_{G}^{rh} \rangle $ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{B_{rh}}} (\sum_{t =0}^{1}e^{I\pi rtR_{t}^{rh}}|t\rangle|t\oplus h\rangle) $

Now according to general measurements done by Bob on his qubits, we have four possible states between  Alice and Charlie’s locations respectively. These four possible states based on Bob’s measurement outcomes are

$|\chi^{rh} \rangle$  = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{M_{rh}}} \sum_{i, q=0}^1 (\sum_{j=0}^1 e^{-I\pi rj}R^{rh}_{j}a_{ij}b_{j\oplus h, q})|iq\rangle$

where

$M_{rh}$ = $\sum_{i, q=0}^1 (\sum_{j=0}^1 e^{-I\pi rj}R^{rh}_{j}a_{ij}b_{j\oplus h, q})^2$

I was unable to understand how ℎ resolves to a value when I take (r, h) as (0, 0)?

Comment: please refrain from posting screenshots of text. You can just link to the relevant paper and type the relevant quotes in the post. Also, could you be more specific as to what exactly the problem you are facing is, and what your current understanding of the topic is? Note that you can use mathjax to type math in the site

Comment: note that you can edit the post to add all the details necessary to understand the question